# XAMPP stuck in an infinite Loop

Tags: xampp

My Xampp has suddenly stopped working .One thing which I recently installed was K-lite codec pack which I uninstalled after this problem came up , I have restarted the machine several times , cleared all browser cache , tried multiple browsers(Chrome,Firefox,IE) . I dont have skype so it cant be that either .

The browser just gets stuck , not even a "`Link is broken/Unable to connect`" is shown . The loading circle in the browser tab just keeps spinning .

I have even changed the config file , setting *localhost* to port 8080 but even that does not cut it .

Restarted Apache service several times(however I am not able to end the service from control panel , it shows error:-1)

I have also run a full computer scan with updated Anti Virus .

I am using Windows 7 on a Dell Latitude
Someone please help me out .
P.S.: I dont have IIS installed either .

Edit : I think there was a virus in the system which modified the hosts file , it commented out *localhost* in the file . The antivirus did not pick it up of course . However the problem still persists . Any other file I should look into which could have been modified by the virus ? I have already reset the hosts file back to default and re started the system.

Comment: Have you tried using your local ip? e.g. http://192.168.0.1:8080 or http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Tried with 127.0.0.1 , produces the same effect . The other two (written above ) are timed out .

Comment: 192.168.0.1 was just an example. You would need to figure out your actual ip, but if 127.0.0.1 doesn't work, using the local ip will most likely not help. It wouldn't surprise me if your security software is blocking the ports used by Apache.

Comment: I disabled the security software for a while , did not work out , also the firewall feature on my software has been in disabled state during the entire time .

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting your server (your PC)

sometimes some PHP application was locked (because of an infinite loop)

Comment: Done that multiple times already , No result .And I cant even access the xampp landing page , rather than any specific application .

Comment: Xampp is in `portable mode`?

Answer (score 0):

You may try uninstall the *apache* service and then try to start apache from *xampp-control.exe*

If everything else fails, as you have said in your post, then you can uninstall *xampp* without uninstalling mysql databases and *htdocs* directory and then reinstall *xampp* again..

Also post a screenshot of the actual error that's coming up in the browse window..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. It's not the problem with server. I think you created an infinity loop in js/php. NEVER do that. In js you need to create event instead of infinity loop:

```js
$('#foo').on('input', function(){
  $('#display').text('Text you typed in is: ' + $('#foo').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="foo">
<div id="display">Text at the load</div>
```

And in php infinity loop will stop the server. PHP is script that is executed on the server. When you create an infinity loop the server cannot end the script, so never return the result and in your browser you will see "Timed out" after 30s (Sometimes it's 1m, 15s etc.).